# dynamic sql selection in nested select

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Let's say that I have a tables `tasks`, `projects`, and `work_items`, all of which have a column `fields` containing a json object of custom values.

Now lets say I want to write a function to query an arbitrary table for its field names.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFieldNames(varchar) RETURNS varchar[] AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  fieldNames varchar[];
BEGIN
  fieldNames := ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT fieldName FROM 
    (EXECUTE 'SELECT json_object_keys(fields) AS fieldName FROM '
      || quote_ident($1)
    ) AS derivedFields
  );
  RETURN fieldNames;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This however errors out with:

```
  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'SELECT json_object_keys(fields) AS fieldName FROM'"
 LINE 8:         (EXECUTE 'SELECT json_object_keys(fields) AS fieldNa..
```

The Nested select itself is sound as I verified by replacing the execute with

```
   (SELECT json_object_keys(fields) AS fieldName
     FROM tasks
    )
```

and receiving correct results.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXECUTE` statement does not return a relation that you can use as a sub-query. Instead, if it returns anything at all, it populates a variable or a single row through the `INTO` clause. The latter obviously does not match your requirement so you are stuck with the first. A more elegant solution is to move the `EXECUTE` statement outwards:

```
EXECUTE
  'SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT fields) FROM ' ||
    '(SELECT json_object_keys(fields) AS fields FROM ' || quote_ident($1) || ') AS x'
INTO fieldNames;
```

Comment: Thank you. You are correct that array_agg with a select into is way more elegant.

However I keep getting the following exception:

ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
Any thoughts?

Comment: @AbrahamP: The DISTINCT clause does not like the set of records coming from the JSON function. Solve it by using a sub-query; see my updated answer.

Comment: @AbrahamP: I don't think I have the SO scholar badge yet, but I am happy enough to be called a gentleman!

Answer (score 0):

The worst issue is wrong position of EXECUTE statement. It is a PLpgSQL statement and then it cannot be placed in any SQL expression.